# Find the value of an integer $a$ such that $ a^2 +6a +1 $ is a perfect square.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratics

I was able to solve this but it required me using hit and trial at one step. I was wondering if i could find a more solid method to solve it.

p.s. this is the first time im asking a question here so sorry if i couldn't construct the question properly.

this is my solution -

$a^2 + 6a + 1 = k^2$

$(a+3)^2 = k^2 + 8$

$k^2 + 8 = m^2 $    where [$m=a+3$]

$(m-k)(m+k) = 8$ ... here by inspection $m= 3$ and $k =1$

hence, $a = 0, -6$.

Comment: ur asked to find "a value". so just say that $a=0$ works

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Observe that $a^2+6a+9$ is always a square.

Comment: Which step did you need a lot of trial & error for?

Comment: @J.G. No i didnt use a lot of trial and error in any step. But i was referring to the step where i had to separately check the factors of 8 which satisfied the equation, i got lucky because 8 has only 4 factors, but it would have been a problem otherwise, which is why i wanted a more solid approach to this.

Comment: @KaranAbrol Another way to find squares differing by $8$ is to note that, because the consecutive gaps are the odd numbers, the larger square has to be less than $25$ (since $25-16>8$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\\(a+1)^2=a^2+2\cdot a+1\leq a^2+6\cdot a + 1 <a^2+6\cdot a+9=(a+3)^2
\\(a+1)^2\leq a^2+6\cdot a+1\leq(a+2)^2
\\=>
$$
if $\>a^2+6\cdot a + 1\>$ is a perfect square if and only if $\>a^2+6\cdot a + 1=(a+1)^2\>$ or $\>a^2+6\cdot a + 1=(a+2)^2\>=>\>a=0\>$ or $\>a=-6$

Comment: Oh wow i did exactly this in the beginning but completely missed equating it to $(a+2)^2$ ..thanks

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

$$a^2+6a+1=b^2$$

$$\iff a^2+6a+1-b^2=0$$

the reduced  discriminant is

$$\Delta'=9-1+b^2=b^2+8$$

$$a=-3\pm \sqrt{b^2+8}$$

thus
$$b^2+8=c^2$$
and
$$(c+b)(c-b)=8$$
$$=4×2=-4×(-2)$$

$$c+b=\pm 4,\;\; c-b=\pm 2$$
gives $$\;\; b=\pm 1$$
and in all cases,
$$a=0 \text{ or } a=-6$$

Comment: I think this is basically what i did. Thanks !! :)

Comment: @KaranAbrol What is an inspection.

Comment: I think it is easiest simply to complete the square here and to write $(a+3)^2-8=b^2$ which get's to the same place, but why worry about the discriminant.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah basically i meant by checking all factors of 8 to get a suitable answer...its hard to explain in this case since 8 has only 4 factors.

Answer (score 0):

Everything to $(m-k)(m+k) = 8$ is valid.

Note $m-k$ and $m+k$ have the same parity because $(m+k) - (m-k) = 2k$ is even so $m-k$ and $m+k$ are both even or both odd.  And as$(m-k)(m+k)$ is even they are both even  That cuts your trial and error by quite a bit.

The only the complete even factors of $8$ is $8 = \pm 2\cdot \pm 4$.  So one of $m+k, m-k$ is $\pm 2$ and the other is $\pm 4$.

So $|(m-k) - (m+k)| = 2|k|$ and $|(m-k) - (m+k)| = |\pm 4 - \pm 2| = 2$ so $k =\pm 1$.

So $a+3 = \pm 3$ and $a = 0, 6$.